# How I can deploy my GWT application on www

Tags: gwt, tomcat

I created my first Java EE application (GWT + Hibernate). I  want deploy my application on a Tomcat web server.

Could you give me a step by step tutorial?

Comment: You need to inform what do you mean by "internet". Are you trying to deploy to Google App Engine or are you trying to deploy to a tomcat instance in a local box?

Comment: By Internet I mean my server www.

Comment: Where is the server hosted? Which domain + host service are you using for your JEE application. Google App Engine provides support for jee apps. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with **Google App Engine + GWT** tutorial if you are trying out deploying into Google Cloud - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine

Answer (score 0):

This question is massive so I will try to bring it down to some steps that need some research to implement.

1st. You created an application using GWT and Hibernate. That means that you need some kind of a web server that **understands** java and can **re-write** the logic from java to javascript (for the clientside), and also connect to the database on the serverside and retrieve the data for the client.

This web server is tomcat so what you need is:

1. A computer that will work as a server. This could be your own machine or some server you can buy as a hosting solution. Buying something like this requires research and effort on your part and cannot be explained here.
2. A version of Tomcat or Resin or any other web server that understands java
3. A domain name. These can be bought [from sites like this one](http://www.domain.com/), but there are some free ones around the web. They require **static ips** that is you cannot use them from a home line that changes ips. Even **without** a domain name you can host your site on the server but you need to access it by writing the machine's ip instead. - optional - A temporary solution would be to use some kind of dynamic dns service on your router.
4. After having set up tomcat (you might want to give port 80 to tomcat) and the server you can host your application by uploading the war file. You can make a war file from gwt by following the instructions [here](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/)
5. To upload the war file you can use the tomcat manager interface, or you can connect to the server and place it manually in the folder used for the web applications.

I know that each step propably needs as much if not more explanation by I hope I cleared the area a little bit here.